# Ubuntu 16.04: how to boot into nomodeset from GRUB2 tty? Laptop with only NVIDIA M1000M

Tags: 16.04, drivers, grub2, nvidia

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a laptop solely equipped with NVIDIA M1000M graphics card. During installation I was able to edit the boot options from the GRUB menu (the one with try without installing, install, install as OEM) and add nomodeset to the boot command. If I didn't do this I would get a purple screen rather than the installation process.

Once Ubuntu 16.04 was installed, however, I can't figure out how to add nomodeset or boot into a terminal-only mode so I can install the necessary drivers. These are the things I tried:

1. hold <kbd>shift</kbd> while booting to load GRUB menu, but it never loads.
2. hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F[1-6]</kbd> to go to terminal but didn't work.
3. hold <kbd>Esc</kbd> while booting gets me to the GRUB terminal. how can I boot into a nomodeset or terminal only mode from here to install the right drivers?

For context (not sure if these are relevant): BIOS has UEFI, 2HDs with RAID0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*The easiest way to do this is to boot from the **live Ubuntu CD** and [boot into the interface with **nomodset**.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162076)*

Now mount your hardisk by clicking to the **left bar** that shows the icon of your harddisk, nautilus will open, now **close it**.

*Open the terminal and type:*
**sudo nautilus**

The the Nautilus file manager will open once again.
Into the Nautilus click your harddisk icon (*usually is bunch of numbers*) to see your folders.

Open these folders:
**etc** - **default**

See the flie named **grub**
Open the file grub with **gedit**

Now search for the line that says:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

And add the nomodset command to look like this:  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="**nomodset** quiet splash"

**Save** and Quit gedit.
**Restart** and remove Ubuntu CD to boot from your harddisk.

To remove the nomodset command from your grub after you are done removing the proprietary Nvidia drivers open a terminal and:
**sudo su**
**cd //**
**gedit /etc/default/grub**

Is highly recommended to do not use the proprietary drivers since everything works fast and without tearing problems except if you are using Kali Linux with Nvidia cuda which is a different "dark" story.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When I boot from the live USB I don't see a screen like

https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162076

Instead it takes me straight to a menu with options 

Try Ubuntu
Install Ubuntu
OEM Install
Check for Defects

If I press c I am able to enter the grub terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I disabled UEFI secure boot in BIOS, and this allowed me to boot with into GRUB menu rather than directly or into GRUB terminal.